# How to extend OWIN Cookie before expiry?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, owin-middleware, cookie-authentication

I'm trying to handle ASP.net MVC 5, timeout session scenario. Here is my code I'm using which is working as well for session expiry.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = 200,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Index"),
            SlidingExpiration=true,
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = ApplicationCookieIdentityValidator.OnValidateIdentity(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

I have to extend/override this expiry whenever user is shown a popup for the expiry of the session. Is there any workaround of overriding or extending the timeout just before it's actual expiry. I need a solution which can be integrated across all the application, Maybe 1 ajax centralized call to server to do that or any other options if there is any?

Thanks.